# Google Maps and GWT: how to put a text label on a map?

Tags: google-maps, gwt, label

I am using this api
 http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/maps/1.1/index.html
, the GWT Google Maps API, in my application.

Now I want to render some text on different coordinates on the map. But.... how?

I have googled around, but it seems there isn't a clear solution?

Any ideas if/how it is possible using some sort of JSNI solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add markers to the map as described in the [GWT Maps Getting started Guide](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/MapsGettingStarted):

```
LatLng cawkerCity = LatLng.newInstance(39.509, -98.434);
map.addOverlay(new Marker(cawkerCity));
```

If you want to render your text directly on the map, you can extend com.google.gwt.maps.client.overlay.Overlay (to create a text overlay). An example of a custom map overlay can be found at http://timlwhite.typepad.com/blog/2008/08/creating-custom-google-maps-overlays-with-gwt-widgets.html

Comment: is there way of doing this without having to specify longitude and latitude and only providing the name of a city/county/state?